# Facebook C# SDK and Web API - (OAuthException - #120) (#120) Invalid album id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-web-api

I have a client app that authenticates to Facebook and then furnishes the access token to Web API methods that are using the Facebook C# SDK, such as posting to the user's photo album:

```
var facebook = new FacebookClient(photoDTO.FacebookSessionToken);

dynamic result = facebook.Post("me/photos",
                    new
                    {
                        message = photoDTO.Photo.Comments,
                        file = new FacebookMediaObject
                        {
                            ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                            FileName = fileName,
                        }.SetValue(imageBytes)
                    });
```

This code used to work, however now I am getting an exception:  "(OAuthException - #120) (#120) Invalid album id".  I believe that this error has something to do with the authentication token, but I've checked that the token is valid by browsing to https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=... and it does correctly return the profile of the user currently logged into the app.  I am using SDK version 6.0.10.0.

How can I post to the currently logged in user's profile using the authentication token passed from the client app?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this an answer or just a workaround but since I knew the name of the album I wanted to post to, I queried the user's albums to get the album id and then used that to post directly to the album:

```
var facebook = new FacebookClient(photoDTO.FacebookSessionToken);

string albumId = null;
string albumName = "Album";
dynamic albums = facebook.Get("me/albums");

// Get the album id of the album we want to post to
foreach(dynamic albumInfo in albums.data)
{
    if (albumInfo.name == albumName)
    {
        albumId = albumInfo.id;
        break;
    }
}

// If album does not exist, create it
if (albumId == null)
{
    dynamic album = facebook.Post("me/albums",
                        new
                        {
                            name = albumName
                        });

    albumId = album.id;
}

// Post the photo to the album                
dynamic photo = facebook.Post("/" + albumId + "/photos",
                    new
                    {
                        message = photoDTO.Photo.Comments,
                        file = new FacebookMediaObject
                        {
                            ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                            FileName = fileName,
                        }.SetValue(imageBytes)
                    });
```

Comment: You need the equivalent id of the /me album though.

Possibly that is the point of the change by Facebook, you would need increased permissions to irate through the user's albums?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Album ID is different from Album name , this is your issue  you are comparing album ID to album Name ! check the album api [**here**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/album)

the proper algorithm is to :

**find album ID , if it is there , then post the media to specified ID , else handle the error**

```
FB.api(
    "/{album-id}",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        //album was found , your code goes right here.
      }
     else {
        //album was not found handle your error.
      }

    }
);
```

Comment: But /me was a well known album name that was present for everyone and had some unique properties. That has been removed. HAs it been replaced by something else? Has it just bene withdrawn from the api? Is it just a permission issue?

Comment: @JamesWestgate if the album ID returns in the result response , then you will get answer for many questions you are asking , if it doesn't return , and you are sure it exists , this is another issue then , and you will have to clarify further stuff so i can help you.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help so far. I offered the bounty although I didn't ask the question. In terms of the bounty offered, it could be rewarded if there is a way to find the album id that was referenced by the /me portion of /me/photos, and detailing what permission this requires over the old approach which didn't require any.

Comment: @JamesWestgate i dont help people to get bounty , i help people cause it makes me feel happy :) , hope i could help you.